# If $x^2\equiv1\pmod5$, what can be said about $x \pmod5$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

(ENC 2000) If $x^2\equiv1\pmod5$, $x\in\mathbb{N},$ then:

> A)  $x\equiv1\pmod5$
>
> B) $x\equiv2\pmod5$
>
> C) $x\equiv4\pmod5$
>
> D) $x\equiv1\pmod5$ or $x\equiv4\pmod5$
>
> E) $x\equiv2\pmod5$ or $x\equiv4\pmod5$

I tried $$x^2\equiv1\pmod5\Longrightarrow5\mid1-x^2\Longrightarrow5\mid(1+x)(1-x)$$ Hence $$5\mid(1-x)\;\;\text{or}\;\;5\mid(1+x)$$ If $$5\mid1-x\Longrightarrow x\equiv1\pmod5$$  If $$5\mid 1+x\;\;?$$

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, I'm Sorry. Edited.

Comment: You almost have it, @marcelolpjunior: at the end it is $$\text{If}\;\;5\mid(1+x)\implies x=-1\pmod 5\ldots$$

Comment: @DonAntonio If $x\equiv -1\pmod5\Longrightarrow x\equiv 4\pmod5$

Comment: Alternative (D)

:)

Comment: You can quickly rule out A-C, since $x^2\equiv 1\bmod{p}$ implies $(-x)^2\equiv 1\bmod{p}$ and $x\not\equiv -x\bmod{p}$ implies $p=2$ or $p\mid x$, so there are two solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^2\equiv1\pmod5\Longrightarrow5\mid1-x^2\Longrightarrow5\mid(1+x)(1-x)$$$$\text{Soon}\;\;\;5\mid(1-x)\;\;\text{or}\;\;5\mid(1+x)$$$$\text{If}\;\;\;5\mid1-x\Longrightarrow x\equiv1\pmod5$$  $$\text{If}\;\;5\mid 1+x\Longrightarrow x\equiv -1\pmod5\Longrightarrow x\equiv4\pmod5$$$$$$Alternative (D)

Comment: Tank you Don Antonio and  AWerthein.

Comment: Good work! +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

$$x^2=1\iff x^2-1=0\iff (x-1)(x+1)=0\iff x=\pm 1$$

The above is true in any field...

Comment: This is a good answer, but I do not know if the op is familiar with what a field is, or the result that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a field for $n$ prime.

Comment: Perhaps you are right, @AWertheim ....Let's see if he knows it or maybe someone else can profit from it. Anyway, finite prime fields is one of the very first things I was taught in first year linear algebra I: they didn't want to restrict themselves to the well known good old rationals, reals and complex.

Comment: Indeed, I did not mean to suggest that it would not be beneficial to the OP or anyone else reading this question. It is a fine answer. +1 :)

Comment: @AWertheim I did not understand, looked my attempt? I'm on the wrong track?

Comment: On the contrary, @marcelolpjunior. You are the the exact right track. Check DonAntonio's other comment.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You know $x \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ is one possibility. What is $4^{2}\pmod 5$? Are there any others possibilities such that $x^{2} \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ in the list?